# C# .Net Core using MSTest to test a downstream API call and getting 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, mstest

I have a .net core 6 application that calls a downstream API. The code works correctly when running it in the application and correctly returns data when the endpoint is called from the Swagger UI but when I call it from a MSTest method I am getting a 401.

The "start up" configuration is identical in the test project to the startup in the application. Below is an example:

```
public static ServiceProvider CreateConfigurationForTest()
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

            configurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                options
                    .Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAppConfig"))
                    // Load global settings
                    .Select("Global.*", LabelFilter.Null)
                    // Load configuration values with no label
                    .Select(AzureConfigApplicationName + ".*", LabelFilter.Null)
                    // Override with any configuration values specific to current hosting env
                    .Select("Global.*", ConfigurationLabel)
                    .Select(AzureConfigApplicationName + ".*", ConfigurationLabel)

            );


            configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
            

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAd")
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddDownstreamWebApi(Constants.CherwellDataAPI, options =>
                {
                    options.BaseUrl = configuration["Global.ApiUrl.Cherwell"];
                    options.Scopes = "api://8f4486da-f763-4a2c-8ce9-dba4d1fa04d1/.default";
                })
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddControllers();



                .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration)
                .AddScoped<IFacilityHelper, FacilityHelper>()
                

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            return serviceProvider;
}
```

Comment: Are you and admin?  VS doesn't run in Admin mode unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The exe from VS does run As Admin.  So error may be you are not an Admin.  The authorization can be part of the URL or an HTTP Header.  Your cookie may also be outdated and need to use a fresh cookie.